# API GMB: remove translated by google in review content

Tags: google-my-business-api

I am using API google my business to retrieve reviews in account's locations.
In the review content, Google includes "(translated by google)" followed by the text translated.
Is there any way to remove this, I mean getting only the original text of user without this translation.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Got that problem too... Can't find any options for that...
As a workaround you can split the review on "(Translated by Google)" and keep the left part of the split :(

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex !

```
\(.*\)
```

[image: Screen from regex101.com]

But doesn't work if review contain "()"